# Openlayers installation

Tags: openlayers, installation

I am confused regarding the OpenLayers installation. In the [official page](https://openlayers.org/download/) it says it is highly recommended to download using `npm install ol` while in this [page](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.5.0) you can download just the zip file.

So which one is the best approach ?

I used npm and it creates a **node-modules** folder and I am getting a message that says `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my-installation-path/package.json'`. While going through the node modules folder I can't find the **ol.js** file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any npm based project, you'll need to create a `package.json` file in the project root.

To set up your JavaScript project with OpenLayers, follow the [README of the ol package](https://npmjs.com/package/ol). Choose one of the ways linked there to bundle your application with OpenLayers, which is basically a standard JavaScript project setup. I'd recommend the [Webpack & Uglify](https://gist.github.com/tschaub/79025aef325cd2837364400a105405b8) one. Following these instruction, you will get the correct `package.json` file and a working webpack configuration.

Comment: thank you..!!! I use the first approach. I had to create a package.json file for which I was not aware. What I don't understand is how to use it. I mean if I use import it throws an error stating Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import. Is the import keyword supposed to be used with frameworks only?  If I don't use import I get Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined.  I can't seem to find the ol.js file to include it

Comment: Also: why can't I just use the zip code from this page  http://openlayers.org/download/   ?  Thank you

Comment: You can of course download the zip from there. But the modern way of building web applications is the one I outlined in my answer. To make the build setup work, run `npm install` first, and then `npm run build`. This will build your application. Then open `index.html`.